# How to replace or convert withcolumn of spark function?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

```
data = status.select("data")
df = data.withColumn("addr", col("data.addr")) \
     .withColumn("time", col('data.time'))\
```

[image]

I want replace or convert "time" column to seconds(bigint).
ex) 13days, 23:41   >>>>> 13x3600x24 + 23x3600 + 41x60 >>> 1208460

Comment: @falsetru How to do image edit?

Comment: You should specify  as `![image descript](image url)`, but it was `[image descript](image url)`. I prepended the missing `!`.

Comment: Oh! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **`split`** function then multiply days with 24*3600..etc.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
#+-------------+
#|         time|
#+-------------+
#|13days, 23:41|
#|12days, 22:52|
#+-------------+

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumn("tmp",split(col("time"),"days,")[0]).\
withColumn("tmp1",split(trim(split(col("time"),"days,")[1]),":")).\
withColumn("time",(col("tmp")*3600*24 + col("tmp1")[0]*3600 + col("tmp1")[1]*60).cast("long")).\
drop(*['tmp','tmp1']).\
show()
#+-------+
#|   time|
#+-------+
#|1208460|
#|1119120|
#+-------+
```